# laravel dompdf get pagenumber in view

Tags: php, css, pdf, laravel, dompdf

I am using following code for make and download pdf files.

**MyController.php**

```
   $pdfTemplate = View::make('sample', $data)->render();
   $pdf = App::make('dompdf');
   $pdf->loadHTML($pdfTemplate);
   return $pdf->download('sample_file.pdf');
```

**sample.php**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
here by using php i need to display div based on page number
<div>This is in page 1</div>
<div>This is in page 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I suppose your use case is a bit more of a challenge, because otherwise you could just style the second DIV with `page-break-before: always;`. Do you have a more fleshed out example? This is probably going to be difficult to do with dompdf because of the way it parses documents.